# Understanding Sklearn's Linear Regression Weighting

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I'm having difficulty getting the weighting array in `sklearn`'s Linear Regression to affect the output.

Here's an example with no weighting.

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn import linear_model

x = np.arange(0,100.)
y = (x**2.0)

xr = np.array(x).reshape(-1, 1)
yr = np.array(y).reshape(-1, 1)

regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
regr.fit(xr, yr)
y_pred = regr.predict(xr)

sns.scatterplot(x=x, y = y)
sns.lineplot(x=x, y = y_pred.T[0].tolist())
```

[image]

Now when adding weights, I get the same best fit line back. I expected to see the regression favor the steeper part of the curve.  What am I doing wrong?

```
w = [p**2 for p in x.reshape(-1)]
wregr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
wregr.fit(xr,yr, sample_weight=w)
yw_pred = regr.predict(xr)

wregr = linear_model.LinearRegression(fit_intercept=True)
wregr.fit(xr,yr, sample_weight=w)
yw_pred = regr.predict(xr)

sns.scatterplot(x=x, y = y)                      #plot curve
sns.lineplot(x=x, y = y_pred.T[0].tolist())      #plot non-weighted best fit line
sns.lineplot(x=x, y = yw_pred.T[0].tolist())     #plot weighted best fit line
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to an error in your code. Fitting of your weighted model should be:

```
yw_pred = wregr.predict(xr)
```

rather than

```
yw_pred = regr.predict(xr)
```

With this you get:

[image]